# Getting list of error messages from ModelState with Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

Is it possible to create one chained linq statements to create an IEnumerable(Of String) of error messages from ViewData.ModelState?

I have tried:

```
Dim errorlist = ViewData.ModelState.Select(
    Function(m) m.Value.Errors.Select(
        Function(e) e.ErrorMessage))
```

But that linq produces IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of String)).

Comment: Try SelectMany instead of Select

Comment: @karaxuna Thanks! Will you post it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim errorlist = ViewData.ModelState.SelectMany(
Function(m) m.Value.Errors.Select(
    Function(e) e.ErrorMessage))
```